# multiplication of two integer arrays

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class that stores arbitrarily large integers in the model of a little-endian character array. I need to overload the multiplication operator, and I cannot think of an algorithm that works. Every solution I come up with is hindered by needing to store some values within a `int`,`double`, or even `long long`. all of which are invalid considering these arrays may theoretical contain an infinite number of digits.

Can anybody help me think of an algorithm for multiplication of large arrays?
(i created a function for converting a single digit integer into a character, and vice versa)

`array1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}`
`array2 = {8,7,6,5,4,3,2}`
`array3 = product`

987654321

x 2345678

=________

when `array1` and `array2` may be infinitely long.

***The use of stdlib classes is prohibited, so no BigInt or Vector**

Comment: Just write code that does the paper-and-pencil method that you learned in elementary school.

Comment: Also, you should be first starting out with "small" BigInt numbers i.e. 2 or 3 digit numbers that may have a carry or two.

Comment: I wouldn't take it for granted that they still teach this in elementary school. If they did, I'd expect that this question would never be asked, since that's so obvious.

Comment: "i created a function for converting a single digit integer into a character, and vice versa" --> post that code.

Comment: I understand this might be a simple solution, but I perform long multiplication the way elementary school children were taught, which involves the summation of multiple product values starting with the ones place or the zeroth element of a little-endian array, but when the 600th digit results in a product too large for a `long long` to store, I get confused. I would need to create storage for an arbitrarily large array, containing arrays, and then add them all, which seems like i'm overcomplicating things given i'm extremely new to c++ and this is a low-level assignment.